# Working on two different devices / not polluting repo

Tags: git, version-control

I am the maintainer of an open source project hosted on GitHub (public repository).

Due to my current working pattern, I have to work on more than one device on the source code. That leads to situations where I have to switch between two devices in order to continue coding.

Back when I had a private repository I would just commit to the `develop` branch (or any feature branch for that matter) and pushed to `origin` on one device and pulled/rebased on the other one. No meaningful commit message, no build-able status on some occasions.

Now, working on a public repository I do not want to 'pollute' the branches so I wonder: What would be the best course of operation?

Is there anyone having good advice for me?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you can create private GitHub repository:

#### Setup

1. Create new private GitHub repository e.g. `example/example-private`
2. In your local repository, which cloned from public repository, add new remote origin:

```
$ git remote add origin-private https://github.com/example/example-private.git
```

3. Push all the local repository to private repository:

```
$ git push origin-private
```

#### Develop with private repository.

4. Create private branch:

```
$ git checkout -b develop-private
```

5. Push to private repository:

```
$ git push -u origin-private develop-private`
```

Now you can share `develop-private` with multiple devices via private repository.

#### When development in private is done

6. merge or rebase `develop-private` branch with your public develop branch.
7. push it to public develop branch

Answer (score 0):

So the problem is, you don't want to commit your undone work for example. If I were on your situation I would do this in this way.

1. `git add .`
2. `git commit -m "work in progress, don't checkout from this commit`

And when you are on another device, after downloading changes that you did on first device. I'll do.

1. `git reset --soft HEAD~1`

And in that way you have your work on another device and public repository is free of useless commit.